# ERROR in Metadata version mismatch for module /node_modules/angular2-cool-storage/index.d.ts, found version 4, expected 3,

Tags: angular, local-storage, coolstorage

I am getting below error on  running `ng build` command.
removed node_modules folder and npm installe giving below warning

```
npm WARN angular2-cool-storage@3.1.2 requires a peer of @angular/core@5.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN angular2-cool-storage@3.1.2 requires a peer of @angular/common@^5.0.0 but none was installed.
```

And for ng build below id deetail error:

> ERROR in Metadata version mismatch for module
>   /node_modules/angular2-cool-storage/index.d.ts, found version 4,
>   expected 3, resolving symbol AppModule in /src/app/app.module.ts
>   resolving symbol AppModule in /src/app/app.module.ts

Package.json is

```
{
  "name": "nova-angular",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.4.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "^2.0.0-beta.12",
    "@angular/common": "^4.4.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.4.3",
    "@angular/core": "^4.4.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.4.3",
    "@angular/http": "^4.4.3",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.4.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.4.3",
    "@angular/router": "^4.4.3",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-alpha.29",
    "angular2-cool-storage": "^3.1.0",
    "angular2-jwt": "^0.2.3",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^2.5.0",
    "ng2-cookies": "^1.0.12",
    "ng2-truncate": "^1.3.10",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.2",
    "tslint-fix": "^0.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.16"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.3.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.4.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.4.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "^8.0.26",
    "codelyzer": "^3.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "^1.2.0",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.4",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.3.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.4.2",
    "typings": "^2.1.1"
  }
}
```

Earlier I used ***angular2-cool-storage*** and now after installing and using ***ng2-cookies*** ng build is failing.
Please suggest me a solution.

Comment: For package consistency, I updated my package.json file.
Removed caret(^) from the package name so now it is not updating package headers.
it forces npm to stick with that version.

"angular2-cool-storage": "^3.1.0" => "angular2-cool-storage": "3.1.0"

Answer (score 4):

It seems there are a package compatibility problem, you should follow this [guide](https://angular-update-guide.firebaseapp.com/) to upgrade packages to angular 5 to make compatible versions for packages, I've tried it and it worked well

> npm install @angular/animations@^5.0.0 @angular/common@^5.0.0
>   @angular/compiler@^5.0.0 @angular/compiler-cli@^5.0.0
>   @angular/core@^5.0.0 @angular/forms@^5.0.0 @angular/http@^5.0.0
>   @angular/platform-browser@^5.0.0
>   @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@^5.0.0
>   @angular/platform-server@^5.0.0 @angular/router@^5.0.0
>   typescript@2.4.2 rxjs@^5.5.2

Answer (score 2):

The message seems clear : You need a version of angular core and common that is at least 5.0.0.

Your package file show a 4.4.3 version.

Try updating your packages, or downgrading your dependencies, and try again !

Comment: thanks for the reply.
Earlier we were using same angular 4 and cool storage 3.1.0.
now installed and used in code ng2-cookies then the problem have occurred.

Comment: And if you uninstall cookies, what happens ? does the application run ?

Comment: no it will not run.
that package is used inside the application modules.

Comment: Of course, but I mean if you delete it completely, even from the code. It would allow me to know if the issue comes from cookies, or storage.

Answer (score 1):

For package consistency, I updated my package.json file.
Removed the caret(^) from the package name so now it is not updating package headers.
It forces npm to stick with the specified version only.

```
"angular2-cool-storage": "^3.1.0" => "angular2-cool-storage": "3.1.0"
```

Check package version which is compatible earlier with the same angular version and specify those entries without ^ in package.json if auto upgardation of package occurs `Metadata version mismatch`.